# Best practice to rename a method parameter in a deployed Python module

Tags: python

Say I maintain a Python module with some method `foo()`:

```
def foo(BarArg=None, AnotherArg=False):
   return True
```

But now I'm not satisfied with the PascalCase of my argument names, and would like to rename them as such:

```
def foo(bar_arg=None, another_arg=False):
   ...
```

How can I introduce this change without breaking existing client code?

I wouldn't really want deprecation warnings (but maybe that's the best practice), and also would very much would like to keep my function's name...

For now, `**kwargs` plus some input validation logic is the only solution that comes to mind, but it seems like the wrong direction.

Comment: If all existing uses of your function call by argument position, the name doesn't matter.  If any of those calls use keyword parameters you're stuck, the best thing may be to just leave the names alone.

Comment: Deprecation warnings are very much absolutely "best practice". You should warn your users to update their code, and give them a deadline, e.g. "this warning will be removed in version x.y.z, and will result in an exception thereafter".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a decorator factory to intercept any uses of the incorrect args:

```py
def re_arg(kwarg_map):
    def decorator(func): 
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            new_kwargs = {}
            for k, v in kwargs.items():
                if k in kwarg_map:
                    print(f"DEPRECATION WARNING: keyword argument '{k}' is no longer valid. Use '{kwarg_map[k]}' instead.")
                new_kwargs[kwarg_map.get(k, k)] = v
            return func(*args, **new_kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return decorator


# change your kwarg names as desired, and pass the kwarg re-mapping to the decorator factory
@re_arg({"BarArg": "bar_arg", "AnotherArg": "another_arg"})
def foo(bar_arg=None, another_arg=False):
    return True
```

Demo:

```py
In [7]: foo(BarArg="hello")
DEPRECATION WARNING: keyword argument 'BarArg' is no longer valid. Use 'bar_arg' instead.
Out[7]: True

In [8]: foo(AnotherArg="hello")
DEPRECATION WARNING: keyword argument 'AnotherArg' is no longer valid. Use 'another_arg' instead.
Out[8]: True

In [9]: foo(x="hello")  # still errors out on invalid kwargs
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [9], line 1
----> 1 foo(x="hello")

Cell In [4], line 9, in re_arg.<locals>.wrapped(**kwargs)
      7         print(f"DEPRECATION WARNING: keyword argument '{k}' is no longer valid. Use '{kwarg_map[k]}' instead.")
      8     new_kwargs[kwarg_map.get(k, k)] = v
----> 9 return func(**new_kwargs)

TypeError: foo() got an unexpected keyword argument 'x'

In [10]: foo(another_arg="hello")  # no warning if you pass a correct arg (`bar_arg` has a default so it doesn't show up in `new_kwargs`.
Out[10]: True

In [11]: foo(BarArg="world", AnotherArg="hello")
DEPRECATION WARNING: keyword argument 'BarArg' is no longer valid. Use 'bar_arg' instead.
DEPRECATION WARNING: keyword argument 'AnotherArg' is no longer valid. Use 'another_arg' instead.
Out[11]: True
```

You could get super fancy and leave in the old kwargs alongside the new ones, inspect the signature, extract the old kwargs and build the `kwarg_map` dynamically, but that'd be quite a bit more work for probably not much gain in my opinion, so I'll "leave it as an exercise for the reader".

Another solution would be to simply add a `new_foo` function, transfer the old `foo` implementation over, and simply call `new_foo` from `foo` with the kwarg re-mapping shown above, and with a deprecation warning, but I think this is cleaner than having to maintain a bunch of stubs.

You may also want to check out the `deprecation` library: https://pypi.org/project/deprecation/